# I'm trying to auto populate text fields with a calculation of the user input of one field onto another in javascript

Tags: javascript, user-input

I'm looking to make a calculator that auto-fills a text field with a calculation of `user input * 12`.

The best way I can explain is `user input * 12 = text input field result`.

Code:

```js
function add_number() {
  var monthlyPayment = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
  var maintFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintFees").value);
  var memFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("memFees").value);
  var exchFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("exchFees").value);
  var result = monthlyPayment + maintFees + memFees + exchFees;

  document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;

  function mpTwelve() {
    var monPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
    var monTwe = monPay * 12;

    document.GetElementById("mpTimesTwelve").value = mpTimesTwelve;
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Only thing I can see there is you're defining a function inside another function?

Comment: are you getting an error? why are you defining a function `mpTwelve()` inside of the function `add_number()`? where are you calling the function `mpTwelve()`?

Comment: also note that `GetElementById` is not `getElementById`

Comment: I'm getting a parsing error:unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors. Replace `document.GetElementById("mpTimesTwelve").value = mpTimesTwelve;` to `document.getElementById("mpTimesTwelve").value = monTwe`

See example in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/vywb9mqg/5/#&togetherjs=2ICJ01oHQu